# Why is my result of displaying a collection in meteor - different from Tutorial I am following?

Tags: meteor

I am new to Meteor and a beginner! I am getting "funny" meteor activity when I am trying to follow tutorials! first I can get form entry to collections and then I can not. the browser reloads and does NOT update collection??
Is this a meteor issue or me? How can I get this working in a simple example, and how can I follow what is happening to debug these issues step by step?

Comment: edit your question and include your codes

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not preventing basic form action. in your submit event add this line

```
event.preventDefault();
```

though if you follow tutorial properly, you should have seen this instructions.

Comment: I do have it included:

Comment: I did include it:Template.postForm.events({
 'submit .new-post'(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 const target = event.target;
 var content = target.content.value;
 Post.insert({
  content,
  createdAt: new Date(),
 });

Comment: Thanks, I have it working now! I had multiple collections defined one with uppercase T and the other with lowercase t and was addressing them differently!

Comment: if the solution helped you solve your problem , make sure you mark it as accepted. Or if you solved problem by yourself, post that as an answer.